# how do I deal with this segmentation error

Tags: c, memory-management, segmentation-fault, gdb, storing-data

I keep receiving the same message "segmentation fault: 11"
gdb tells me that the break point is just after the main function. in the line where I declare the int j;
i really do not understand how can that possibly break the code.

the input this function reads is made up of simply 1 string followed by 2 numbers like

john 22 43 sam 11 23

all it's supposed to do is simply to store the entire input in "elenco" and then print the strings.

first i created a struct that matches the input.
then i made a function with the purpose of reading the input and store in a variable.
then i made a function whose variables is the output of the function that read the input ( so the input ) and that prints the strings given

can anybody help me identify the problem and solve it?

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char name[20];
    int distance;
    int point;
}  throw;

throw *read_file(FILE *f, int *j)
{
    int i = 0;
    int c;
    int Dim = 32;
    char buf[1000];
    throw *list;

    list = malloc(Dim *sizeof(*list));
    if (list == NULL)
    {
        (*j) = 0;
        return NULL;
    }
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f)!= NULL)
    { 
        sscanf(buf, "%19s %d %d",
        list[*j].name,
        &list[*j].distance,
        &list[*j].point);
        *j += 1;

        if ( *j >= Dim)
        {
            Dim = Dim*2;
            list = realloc(list, Dim *sizeof(*list));
            if (list == NULL)
            {
                return NULL;           
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}

void print_everything(throw *list, int j)
{
    int c;
    for (c=0; c < j; c++ )
    {
        printf("%d\n",list[c].distance);
    }
}

int main(int argc,const char  *argcv[])
{
    int j = 0;
    FILE *file;
    throw *list;
    if (!( argc != 3))
    {
        printf("file's dimension is wrong\n");
        return -1;
    }

    file = fopen(argcv[1], "r");

    list = read_file(file, &j);

    print_everything(list, j);
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

input1.txt

Mario  20 30
Giorgio 30 40
Mario 40 40
Davide 32 20
Mario 9 32

that is exactly what the file contained

Comment: `if ( i >= Dim)` I can't see where you increment `i` within `Leggi_file`. Probably supposed to be `j` instead of `i`?

Comment: i tried with j,too the results is the same " segmentation fault:11"

Comment: Could you simplify reading your code by translating to English and removing unneeded empty lines? Indentation would be a nice touch.

Comment: `if (!( argc != 3))` instead of `if (( argc == 3))`, why? It complains about getting 2 arguments, but giving none is fine. Then you assume there is at least one, with `file = fopen(argcv[1], "r");`. I would not be surprised by a segfault in that case. With a few other assumptions, `if ( argc != 3)` might solve your problem.

Comment: I think the second `elenco = realloc(elenco, Dim *sizeof(*elenco));` is meant to be `elenco = realloc(elenco, (*j) * sizeof(*elenco));`. Please fix some indentations inconsistencies in your code and remove unneeded empty lines. I only see an overflow can happen in scanf, try with `sscanf(buf, "%19s %d %d",...)` also check if `sscanf` return value is 3. Can the "nome" be longer then 19 characters? I copied your code to [onlinegdb.com and run it](https://onlinegdb.com/r1mnFPzgU), and I got just `22` and `11` in the output. Is there something you are not showing? And you forgot to call `free`

Comment: There may be also another reason - one of the `malloc` or `realloc` calls just fail and return `NULL`. Add error handling code and check if each of the returned pointers is not NULL. Also run your code under a debugger.

Comment: i reduced space and added indentation. then I translated everything in english. now i will add the exact file i am testing. name cannot be longer than 20 character. i'm only giving one argument to the code when i call it.

Comment: i think it should be much more readable right now

Comment: Dare I ask where `elenco` is even *declared* ?

Comment: If you only give one argument, please explain `if (!( argc != 3))`. For programs which rountinely get one argument, I'd expect a 2 instead of 3 and one fewer `!`.

Comment: I took some liberty on your white space. There are different opinions on the perfect scheme, but you should pick one of the more widely used ones. I applied the one which admittedly happens to be my favorite.

Comment: i removed the if (!( argc != 3))  line, because it was not really interesting to me now. it was just an example from a exercise.

Comment: kamilcuk, how is that possible that it work one onlinegdb, but on my mac i receive segmentation fault?

Comment: whozcraig, sorry i had just translated it and i forgot to translate elenco, too. It is "list"

Comment: My pleasure. Now please explain `if (!( argc != 3))`. It is still there and you should not remove it, because a similar line could protect you against at least one potential source of segfaults. Just needs to be done correctly, as I described in a previous comment.

Comment: i'm sorry yunnosch, I don't really know why argc must  be like that. I was told it by the professor. i can tell you that the programm is only given one additional variable

Comment: "how is it possible that it works sometimes but not always".. this is the nature of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). If you do something to break the rules (invoke UB), then all bets are off as to what will happen next. It might work as you expect, it might seg fault (you've observed both of these), it might do something else. UB can manifest itself in different ways depending on the system, the compiler, the compiler options, etc. You must find and fix your UB to have determinant behavior.

Comment: GDB tell me that Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.                                           
_IO_fgets (buf=0x7fffffffe7c0 "\320\350\377\377\377\177", n=1000, fp=0x0)                      
    at iofgets.c:50                                                                            
50      iofgets.c: No such file or directory.                      how to i fix this?

Comment: THANKS EVERYBODY, it finally works. it was quite a trivial mistakes I made witht the input. you gave me lots of good suggestion and polished the few humble lines of code, so thanks a lot

Comment: Tommaso Could you please elaborate? I seem to have a misunderstanding and would like to clarify it. Do I need to take my last edit back? In that case sorry.

Comment: You can even create your own answer to explain how exactly you solved this. It could even be an interesting and helpful one. Or is BobRun exactly right? (I do not need to be right, just want to understand....)

Answer (score 0):

Your program is fine. Your problem is in input1.txt , you need

```
Mario 20 30
Giorgio 30 40
Mario 40 40
Davide 32 20
Mario 9 32
```

Each line needs a \n as you read with fgets()

Comment: THANKS EVERYBODY, it finally works. it was quite a trivial mistakes I made witht the input. you gave me lots of good suggestion and polished the few humble lines of code, so thanks a lot

Comment: Oh sorry. OPs last comment on the question seems to confirm you.... though it confuses me....

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes on you code you are making the use of the lists wrong try to use pointers

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXSTR 250

typedef struct elenco
{
    char *name;
    int distance;
    int point;
    struct elenco *next;
}  throw;

throw *list_add(throw *list, int distance, int point, const char *name)
{
    throw *new = malloc(sizeof(throw));
    if (new != NULL) {
        new->distance = distance;
        new->point = point;
        new->name =(char*)malloc(strlen(name)+1);
        strcpy(new->name,name);
        new->next = list;
        return new;
    }
    return list;
}

throw *read_file(FILE *f)
{
    char buf[MAXSTR];

    throw *list = malloc(sizeof(throw));

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f)!= NULL)
     { 
         char name[MAXSTR];
         int distance;
         int point;
        sscanf(buf, "%s %d %d",
            name,
            &distance,
            &point);

            list = list_add(list, distance, point, name);
}
    return list;
}


void print_everything(throw *list)
{

    while (list) {
        printf("%d\n",list->distance);
        list = list->next;
    }

}


int main()
{
    int argc;
    const char  *argcv;
    FILE *file;

    if (!( argc != 3))
    {
    printf("file's dimension is wrong\n");
    return -1;
    }


    file = fopen(&argcv[1], "r");

    throw *list = read_file(file);
    print_everything(list);

    fclose(file);

return 0;
}
```